# iOS Simulator Works only when app is run from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I have this strange issue where -

1. In viewWillAppear() of a ViewController, I have a function that does a GET service call and stores the response in a global variable.
2. The response is a simple array of strings.

These two steps are working as expected **only when the app is run on the simulator from Xcode.**

When I normally launch the app in Simulator directly (not from Xcode), the service call doesn't work. :-O

I also added this service call to happen asynchronously. Below is my code.

```
override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.fetchCountryTeleCodeList()
        })

    }
```

I can provide more details as required.

**EDIT-1 (Added fetchCountryTeleCodeList code)**

```
func fetchCountryTeleCodeList() {
        self.fetchCountryTeleCodeList { result in
            switch result {
            case let .Success(countryCodeString):
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    countryCodes = countryCodeString as! [String]
                    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "MyApp", message: "\(countryCodes)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()
                })

            case .Failure:
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "MyApp", message: "Internet_Connectivity_Message".localized(), delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()

                })
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT-2 (added fetchCountryTeleCodeList service call implementaion)**

func fetchCountryTeleCodeList(completion:((MyappResult) -> Void)) {

```
    ServiceClientArray.requestJSON(ServiceRequest.FetchCountryTeleCodes) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .Success(myArray as NSArray):
            completion(.Success(myArray))
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "MyApp", message: "\(myArray)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            })

        case let .Failure(error):
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "MyApp", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            })

            completion(.Failure(error))
        default:
            break

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this method do ? - self.fetchCountryTeleCodeList(), can you post the method body ?

Comment: please post this method "self.fetchCountryTeleCodeList()" body so that I can identify the issue

Comment: Edited my question - added code

Comment: What exaclty happens "the service call doesn't work"?

Comment: @shallowThought: in simulator when run through xcode,  I get my countrycodes response. But when launched independently, this method is never called. I've put an alert inside this method since I cannot debug until connected to Xcode. The alert is never shown!

Comment: Shoe `self.fetchCountryTeleCodeList` implementation.

Comment: @shallowThought: edited my question

Comment: @LohithKorupolu put a log print in `default` case.

Comment: @shallowThought: debug never reaches default case.